# Why have I lost reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Ok I am running into a weird issue. Earlier I had 34 or so reputation. Now I have 1 rep. I oddly still have 34 rep on meta.superuser.com. from what I read at https://superuser.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta my meta reputation should be the same as my main site rep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You answered [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/879022/stop-google-from-hiding-results) but it has since been migrated to Webapps as it is off topic for Super User. Your answer on this site was deleted in the process, and the reputation for it (35 points) removed from your account. Your meta account is a bit behind due to caching.

Since your answer is now on Webapps, you'll automatically get +35 reputation on that site if you register and link that account with your SU account.

Comment: Thanks. Now to try and get more rep. I was close to the 50 for being able to comment too. Oh well.